# stack around array variable corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

i am trying to pass my array through my assign and draw functions. the assign function only exists to take the wins array and assign a value of 0 for all of the elements in the array. my draw function fills the array with random numbers 1-100 with 20 numbers in the array. when i try to compile i end up with a runtime error stating that the stack around my variable (array) wins is corrupted. where should i go from here?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

void draw(int a[]);
void assign(int a[]);
int sizeofarray = 20;


int main() {
    int wins[20] = {};

    assign(wins);

    cout << "compiled!" << endl;

}

void assign(int a[20]) {

    a[20] = {};
    draw(a);

}

void  draw(int a[])

{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    int rannum = (1 + rand() % 100);


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        a[i] = 1 + rand() % 100;
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you expect the line `a[20] = {};` to do?

Comment: Use std::fill instead of a[20]={0}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get an error with information as helpful as this, you should immediately be thinking "I have a buffer overflow".  Then go looking for it.

Sure enough, here it is:

```
void assign(int a[20]) {
    a[20] = {};            // <--- BOOM!
    draw(a);
}
```

Your array can only store 20 elements.  When you store something at the 21st element, you have undefined behavior.

Just adding some more information here.  It's *possible* that you thought the offending line would zero-initialize the entire array (like it does when defining the variable).  However, outside of an array definition, this is not the case.  `a[20] = {}` is an assignment.

If you wish to zero the array, use `std::fill` as follows:

```
std::fill(a, a+20, 0);
```

I should point out, however, that there's no point zeroing the array in the context of your code as written.  It's already zeroed on entry, and the `draw` function initializes every element anyway.

Comment: ive actually tried to delete the assignment brackets as well and it seems to have worked, but when i do a function call and try and print the result of the function, it doesnt list the random 20 numbers but rather something looking like a hex code. forgive my lack of knowledge on the subject, but i am just starting out with c++ and i more than happily accept help!

Comment: Decrypting what you're saying, I get the feeling you tried `cout << wins` to print the array.  That only prints the pointer.  If you want to display the contents of the array, you must loop through it and output each value.

Comment: yep i ran it through a loop in the draw function and it worked like a charm. thanks very much paddy