# Debug error even though I get correct output for 2D Matrix multiplication

Tags: c++

I wrote the code to multiply two 2D Matrices in C++ language. I am using VS 2019 and there are no compiler errors.

When I execute the program, it gives me the output as well but I am not sure why I get the Matrix corruption error at run time.

[image]

Here is a simple program I wrote.

```
// CPP_ConsoleApp1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    cout << "Matrix 1" << endl;
    int Matrix1[3][3] = { {1,2,3}, {2,3,1}, {2,1,0} };

    for (int rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < 3; columns++)
        {
            cout << Matrix1[rows][columns] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Matrix 2" << endl;
    int Matrix2[3][2] = { {2,1},{2,2},{1,2} };

    for (int rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
    {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < 2; columns++)
        {
            cout << Matrix2[rows][columns] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int Matrix3[3][2];

    for (int rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                sum = sum + Matrix1[rows][k] * Matrix2[k][column];
            }
            Matrix3[rows][column] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Matrix 1 * Matrix 2" << endl;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
        {
            cout << Matrix3[rows][column] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Matrix3[3][2]` while `(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)` and `(int column = 0; column < 3; column++)`

Comment: It didn't complain about your (correct or wrong) results. (Correct results doesn't need to mean anything.) It did complain about stack corruption around local variables. That's a sure indicator for out of bound write accesses and you should say "Thanks" and take this seriously. ;-)

Comment: I literally just answered [a question just like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58229812/1553090).  You're writing past the end of your buffer.  Matrix3 does not have 3 "columns".  It only has 2.  Your loop filling it is writing off the end, as well as reading off the end of Matrix2.

Comment: spent two days and couldn't see this. you people we extremely fast and quick to figure out. thank you all.